# Mysql cartesian product in where clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, cartesian-product

What i need is cartesian product in WHERE clause:

for example i have cities London, Barcelona, Milan, Paris in one variable, and Berlin in other variable.. i need all combinations in where clause (london-berlin, barcelona-berlin, milan-berlin, paris-berlin).

```
SELECT *
FROM flight
WHERE flight.from = (London, Barcelona, Milan, Paris) AND flight.to = 'Berlin'
```

Comment: i found problem... i was trying with IN clause before i asked question, but problem was that cities were in variable, so my query looked like "..WHERE flight.from IN ('London,Barcelona, Milan,Paris')..." instead of "..WHERE flight.from IN ('London','Barcelona','Milan','Paris')..." so problem was in quotation

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
WHERE flight.from IN ('London', 'Barecelona', 'Milan', 'Paris') AND (flight.to = 'Berlin')
```

Comment: i've tried that before i asked question.. it's not working. Maybe it's because cities in flight table are not string, but id's of cities, but i've used inner join on flight.cities..

Comment: `WHERE flight.from IN (select id from cities where name in (...))` would work for that.

Answer (score 1):

If flight.from is a char/varchar, try;

```
SELECT * FROM flight 
    WHERE `from` IN ('London', 'Barcelona', 'Milan', 'Paris') AND `to`='Berlin';
```